# Why is the modulus $|\cdot|$ not an order on $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

In the complex field, why is the modulus not a good way to make a total order:

$$ a+bi \le c+di \Leftrightarrow |a+bi| \le |c+di|$$

Comment: Alternatively, you could post your own answer and (after the mandatory delay, which I think is a couple of days) accept it. Either would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This relation is not an order because it doesn't satisfy the anti-symmetry property:

Anti-symmetry: $\forall a,b \in C: a\le b \wedge b\le a \Rightarrow a = b$

Here's a counter-example: $-1 \le 1 \wedge 1 \le -1$ but $-1 \neq 1$.